# Is it natural to say "pass exams well"?

Tags: adverbs, phrase-choice

Would a native English speake ever say or ask the following?

> I have passed my all exams well.
>
> Did you pass your exams well?

What I mean by *pass exams well* is pass exams successfully.

Comment: to pass exams with flying colors or with high marks or high grades.

Answer (score 6):

That's not idiomatic.  The main reason is because when you talk about *passing* something (or its opposite, *failing*), it's an either-or matter.  You either passed the exams or didn't.  Using *well* to describe "how much" you passed the exams doesn't make a lot of sense.

If you really want to talk about "how well" you *performed* or *did* your exams, you can say:

> I did very well on all my exams.

You may have to be explicit about passing your exams if it's possible you could have done well but still not passed for some weird reason.

> I passed all my exams; I did very well on all of them!

Comment: An idiom one might want to use here is [*with flying colors*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pass+with+flying+colours).

Comment: ‘With flying colours’ would mean _very_ high marks; more than just ‘well’.

Comment: Closer to the original would be "I passed all my exams easily". This does have two slightly different meanings though: (1) Passed without much effort (2) Passed by a good margin.